# SPARC: Segfault error when using a store instruction

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, sparc

I need to update an element in a long array passed as an argument for this routine by a number also passed as an argument.

```
/*
 * Function Prototype:
 * updateNumber( long * numberAr, long newNumber);
 */

 updateNumber:
         save    %sp, -96, %sp            ! makes the arguments accessible in the in registers
         ld      [%i0], %l0               ! maps numberAr[0] to %l0
         mov     %i1, %l1                 ! puts newNumber in %l1

         st      %l1, [%i0]               ! should store newNumber in numberAr[0], but causes a segfault error
```

I tried loading with ldsb and ldub and storing with stb instead, but those didn't work. What should I check to make this work? 
I recently asked a similar question to this, but I couldn't figure out the solution this time even though the only difference should be that it's with longs instead of chars.

Comment: First, make sure the caller does not pass a read-only array.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be read-only (supported by the instructions of my assignment), but it's probably notable that when I was able to figure out the instructions with my other file, that array was passed from a C file with the notation `numberAr` but this routine is given an array from its corresponding C file as `&numberAr[0]` .

Comment: AFAIR, the address you store to must be a multiple of the size of the value. Is this SPARC 64-bit ? Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models

Comment: I used the `isainfo -v` command, and it says this is 64-bit.

Comment: @Malkocoglu but the read supposedly succeeded, just the write faults...

Comment: To be clear, in this routine the number isn't successfully updated, according to a print statement I have set up.

Comment: So you are not sure it's the write? Comment out the write and see if it still faults. Or, you know, use a debugger :)

Comment: Yup, it's definitely the line `st %l5, [%i0]` (as I have it written on my full code; %l5 just has a number that's expected to go into the long array.)

Comment: Well, it doesn't segfault if I have both `ldsh` and `stb` at the same time. It seems to mess up some other part of my routine, but maybe I can work with it.

Comment: How confident are you that the address of the value that you want to update is where you think it is on the stack?

Comment: Last time when I was updating a 3 element long unsigned char array that went to %i1, it was quite simply `stb    %l5, [%i1+0]` `stb   %l5, [%i1+1]`, and `stb   %l5, [%i1+2]` (I actually used a loop increment for the addition) because a char is one byte, so I assumed the implementation for a long array would be similar.